# How to remove duplicates so that only pairs exist in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a ticket_events table which shows check in and check out timestamps.

```
timestamp               type
2018-12-26 02:46:01 IN
2018-12-26 02:46:13 IN
2018-12-26 03:17:57 OUT
2018-12-26 04:12:13 IN
2018-12-26 04:12:25 IN
2018-12-26 04:35:41 OUT
2018-12-26 04:35:53 OUT
2018-12-26 05:11:05 IN
2018-12-26 06:03:42 OUT
2018-12-26 06:03:55 OUT
2018-12-26 06:04:43 IN
2018-12-26 06:04:50 IN
2018-12-26 06:28:07 OUT
2018-12-26 06:28:19 OUT
2018-12-26 07:00:11 IN
2018-12-26 07:00:22 IN
2018-12-26 07:19:13 OUT
2018-12-26 07:59:21 IN
2018-12-26 08:24:57 OUT
```

I want only IN OUT pairs to appear in the table, with no consecutive IN's or OUT's. So for example I want:

```
timestamp               type
2018-12-26 02:46:01 IN
2018-12-26 03:17:57 OUT
2018-12-26 04:12:13 IN
2018-12-26 04:35:41 OUT
2018-12-26 05:11:05 IN
2018-12-26 06:03:42 OUT
2018-12-26 06:04:43 IN
2018-12-26 06:28:07 OUT
2018-12-26 07:00:11 IN
2018-12-26 07:19:13 OUT
2018-12-26 07:59:21 IN
2018-12-26 08:24:57 OUT
```

Does anyone know a sql query to do this?

My query right now is

```
select timestamp, type from ticket_events where ticket_uuid='value'
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove any row where the previous row has the same type.  So:

```
select timestamp, type
from (select t.*,
             lag(type) over (order by timestamp) as prev_type
      from ticket_events t
     ) t
where prev_type <> type or prev_type is null;
```

The `where` clause can also be phrased as:

```
where prev_type is distinct from type
```

If you want to delete the "offending" rows, you can do the following -- assuming that `timestamp` is unique:

```
delete from ticket_events
    using (select t.*,
                  lag(type) over (order by timestamp) as prev_type
           from ticket_events t
          ) tt
    where tt.timestamp = t.timestamp and
          tt.prev_type = t.type;
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a gap and island problem.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get the gap, then use `group by` with `min`

```
SELECT MIN(timestamp) "timestamp",
       type
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp)-
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) gap
    FROM ticket_events 
    where ticket_uuid='value'
) t1
GROUP BY gap,type
ORDER BY MIN(timestamp)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7a3e8/12/0)**:

```
|            timestamp | type |
|----------------------|------|
| 2018-12-26T02:46:01Z |   IN |
| 2018-12-26T03:17:57Z |  OUT |
| 2018-12-26T04:12:13Z |   IN |
| 2018-12-26T04:35:41Z |  OUT |
| 2018-12-26T05:11:05Z |   IN |
| 2018-12-26T06:03:42Z |  OUT |
| 2018-12-26T06:04:43Z |   IN |
| 2018-12-26T06:28:07Z |  OUT |
| 2018-12-26T07:00:11Z |   IN |
| 2018-12-26T07:19:13Z |  OUT |
| 2018-12-26T07:59:21Z |   IN |
| 2018-12-26T08:24:57Z |  OUT |
```